# FFMPEG C# Winforms Output to Textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, ffmpeg

Trying to write a video compression app using Windows Forms, I can get the file to compress ok, but I'm looking to show the process to something like a textbox?

At the minute the program doesn't have a progress, so you don't know if its complete or not, is it possible to output with FFMPEG is doing to a textbox?

This is my code, when it runs nothing is shown in the textbox:

```
string ffmpeg = @"c:\test\ffmpeg.exe";
            ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(ffmpeg);
            psi.UseShellExecute = false;
            psi.CreateNoWindow = true;

            psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            psi.Arguments = "-i c:\\test\\small.mp4 -s 480x272 c:\\test\\compressed.mp4";

            var proc = Process.Start(psi);

            string s = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

            textBox1.Text = s;
```

Do i need to pass something else into the ProcessStartInfo section?

Comment: See this example http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/492381/StartInfo-RedirectStandardOutp

Answer (score -1):

You need to periodically check back with `proc.StandardOutput` to see if there is new text there. Right immediately after you've started the program, it's no surprise that it hasn't managed to write anything yet.

I'd advise using a [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) for that.